# How do I prevent an "Uncaught TypeError: e is undefined" error when I press the start button on a tic tac toe game?

Tags: javascript

I keep getting an "Uncaught TypeError: e is undefined" error (for functions placeGamePieceO() and startGame() functions) every time I click the start button on the game. What am I doing wrong with the event object?

[image]

```js
const GAMEGRID = document.querySelector("#game-grid");
const GAMESQUARES = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-squares");
const PLAYERO = document.querySelector(".player-o-box");
const STARTBUTTON = document.querySelector("button");

function startGame() {
  placeGamePieceO();
}

function placeGamePieceO(e) {
  PLAYERO.classList.add("player-turn-green");
  PLAYERX.classList.remove("player-turn-green");

  e.target.innerHTML = "O";
  e.target.style.fontSize = "70px";
}

//starts the game
STARTBUTTON.addEventListener("click", startGame, false);

//places O mark on game board
GAMEGRID.addEventListener("click", placeGamePieceO, false);
```

Comment: You need to define e in startGame and pass it to placeGamePieceO `function startGame(e) { placeGamePieceO(e); }`

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS to it

Comment: @danronmoon More likely define a TARGET for the start.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you click start?

Comment: Defining e in startGame(e) and passing it to placeGamePieceO(e) worked. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the answer as a runnable stack snippet?